# Can't load property from API response inside Vue template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am loading the name if the current user inside template but it is not showing, however the object itself is being loaded fine.

```
<div v-if="currentUser">
            Hello {{currentUser.name}}
            Hello {{currentUser}}
          <router-link to="#">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-dark nav-button" @click="logout">Log out</button>
          </router-link>
</div>
```

The output of this is

```
Hello Hello {"name":"John"}
```

So it is loading the object itself but not `name` property.

Comment: I recommend the [Vue Devtools Extension](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools). Try to see what values go into that component. Might it be that `currentUser` is not an object but a plain String containing JSON syntax?

Comment: Can you show what the `currentUser` object look like?

Comment: current user is : ```{"name":"John"}``` and it is being showed inside the DOM, so the object itself get loaded as ```Hello {"name":"John"}``` but the property inside it is not loaded.

Comment: Try adding `{{ typeof currentUser }}` to your template to check whether it's an object or a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the response, I'm guessing your response did not get parsed as JSON

you can try

```html
<div v-if="currentUser">
  Hello {{JSON.parse(currentUser).name}}
  <router-link to="#">
    <button class="btn" @click="logout">Log out</button>
  </router-link>
</div>
```

but doing this in the template is not a good idea. It's better to do it when you're assigning it to the variable in your method

```js
this.currentUser = JSON.parse(response);
```

and then you can use it as you did